# Unexpected list comprehension behaviour in Python

Tags: python, list-comprehension, language-implementation

I believe I'm getting bitten by some combination of nested scoping rules and list comprehensions.  [Jeremy Hylton's blog post](http://www.python.org/~jeremy/weblog/040204.html) is suggestive about the causes, but I don't really understand CPython's implementation well-enough to figure out how to get around this.

Here is an (overcomplicated?) example.  If people have a simpler one that demos it, I'd like to hear it.   The issue:  the list comprehensions using next() are filled with the result from the last iteration.

**edit**: The Problem:

What exactly is going on with this, and how do I fix this?  Do I have to use a standard for loop? Clearly the function is running the correct number of times, but the list comprehensions end up with the *final* value instead of the result of each loop.

Some hypotheses:

- generators?
- lazy filling of list comprehensions?

**code**

```
import itertools
def digit(n):
    digit_list = [ (x,False) for x in xrange(1,n+1)]
    digit_list[0] = (1,True)
    return itertools.cycle ( digit_list)
```

```
>>> D = digit(5)
>>> [D.next() for x in range(5)]
## This list comprehension works as expected
[(1, True), (2, False), (3, False), (4, False), (5, False)]
```

```
class counter(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.counter = [ digit(4) for ii in range(2) ] 
        self.totalcount=0
        self.display = [0,] * 2
    def next(self):
        self.totalcount += 1
        self.display[-1] = self.counter[-1].next()[0]
        print self.totalcount, self.display
        return self.display

    def next2(self,*args):
        self._cycle(1)
        self.totalcount += 1
        print self.totalcount, self.display
        return self.display

    def _cycle(self,digit):
        d,first = self.counter[digit].next()
        #print digit, d, first
        #print self._display
        self.display[digit] = d
        if first and digit > 0:
            self._cycle(digit-1)


C = counter()
[C.next() for x in range(5)]
[C.next2() for x in range(5)]
```

**OUTPUT**

```
In [44]: [C.next() for x in range(6)]
1 [0, 1]
2 [0, 2]
3 [0, 3]
4 [0, 4]
5 [0, 1]
6 [0, 2]
Out[44]: [[0, 2], [0, 2], [0, 2], [0, 2], [0, 2], [0, 2]]

In [45]: [C.next2() for x in range(6)]
7 [0, 3]
8 [0, 4]
9 [1, 1]
10 [1, 2]
11 [1, 3]
12 [1, 4]
Out[45]: [[1, 4], [1, 4], [1, 4], [1, 4], [1, 4], [1, 4]]

# this should be:  [[0,3],[0,4]....[1,4]] or similar
```

Comment: I'm sorry but what's the question?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem is that with `return self.display` you return a *reference* to this list (not a copy). So what you end up with is a list where each element is a reference to self.display. To illustrate, look at the following:

```
>>> a = [1,2]
>>> b = [a,a]
>>> b
[[1, 2], [1, 2]]
>>> a.append(3)
>>> b
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
```

You probably want to use something like `return self.display[:]`.

Answer (score 4):

Mind if i refactor this a bit?

```
def digit(n):
    for i in itertools.count():
        yield (i%n+1, not i%n)
```

But actually you don't need that one, if you implement the whole thing as a simple iterator:

```
def counter(digits, base):
    counter = [0] * digits

    def iterator():
        for total in itertools.count(1):
            for i in range(len(counter)):
                counter[i] = (counter[i] + 1) % base
                if counter[i]:
                    break
            print total, list(reversed(counter))
            yield list(reversed(counter))

    return iterator()

c = counter(2, 4)
print list(itertools.islice(c, 10))
```

If you want to get rid of the print (debugging, is it?), go with a while-loop.

This incindentally also solves your initial problem, because `reversed` returns a copy of the list.

Oh, and it's zero-based now ;)